# how to print an unsized array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printf

I am new to C and trying to figure out how to print an unsized array in C. Using the following code, I have weird looking output and I can't figure out the reason.

I need some help here:

```
main()
{
    int i;
    char *prt_1st;
    char list_ch[][2] = {'1','a', '2','b', '3','c','4','d','5','e','6','f' };

    prt_1st = list_ch;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(list_ch); i++) {
        prt_1st +=  i;
        printf("The content of the array is %c under %d position\n", *prt_1st, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: your array is two-dimensional, but you are initializing it in a one-dimensional fashion. Which is not good. And yes, it is "sized", as the size is inferred from the initializer.

Comment: What is an "unsized array"? Do some research on the `sizeof` operator. While used incorrectly here, it is the thing to solve your problem.

Comment: You should do `prt_1st++;`, not increment with `i`.

Comment: There may be alignment issues, as the compiler may decide to let each row start on a word boundary (32/64 bit boundary) but a row is only 2 bytes.

Comment: "Weird looking output" isn't a very clear problem statement.  Include actual output in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, The problem in your code is, in the following line

```
prt_1st +=  i;
```

It increments your pointer by i times, but what you need is you should increment it by 1.

Here is the modified code

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char *prt_1st;
    char list_ch[][2] = {'1','a', '2','b', '3','c','4','d','5','e','6','f' };

    prt_1st = list_ch[0];

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(list_ch); i++) 
    {
        //prt_1st +=  i;    
        printf("The content of the array is %c under %d position\n", *prt_1st, i);
        prt_1st =  prt_1st + 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An array of undefined length can be printed by getting the number of elements via

Total Size of Elements

Individual Size of Element

In this case

```
    sizeof(list_ch) returns Total array size.
    sizeof(char) returns an individual character size.

therefore,
    Total number of elements (n) = sizeof(list_ch)/sizeof(char)
```

```
iterate the array using


iterate a for loop 
    // Either format your code using ptr format
    *(list_ch+i); 
    // or a 1D Array 
    list_ch[i];
```

or you can just use an incremental solution by just

```
 

printf("%s", list_ch)
++list_ch 



This will automatically put your ptr to the next index in your array
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: For "Individual Size of Element", suggest using the direct approach `sizeof(*list_ch)` or `sizeof(list_ch[0])`

Comment: you already know the datatype is going to be the same so reading the data type through size would suffice everytime and it reads known datatypes faster than some array.

Answer (score 1):

The following works and deals with possible alignment problems:

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char (*prt_1st)[2];
    char list_ch[][2] = {{'1','a'}, {'2','b'}, {'3','c'},{'4','d'},{'5','e'},{'6','f'} };

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(list_ch)/sizeof(list_ch[2]); i++) {
        for (j=0; j<sizeof(list_ch[2]); j++)
            printf("The content of the array is %c under %d,%d position\n", list_ch[i][j], i,j);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: In my solution `sizeof(list_ch[2])` is misleading. It should be either `sizeof(list_ch[0])` (the first row) or `sizeof(char[2])`. Any suggestions?

Comment: `sizeof(list_ch[0])` works for me. Why do you think `list_ch[2]` is misleading?

Comment: I am doing exercise from a book. The definition of the array should maintain. Thank you for the code though. =)

Comment: @Bob, the `list_ch[2]` is misleading because the `2` means the second (third) row and not the size of the dimension.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare and initialize a 2d array with first size unspecified in this way:

```
char list_ch[][2] = {{'1','a'}, {'2','b'}, {'3','c'}, {'4','d'}, {'5','e'}, {'6','f'}};
```

Doing so the result of `sizeof(list_ch)` would be `12`. The elements of the array should be contiguous in memory (unless as @**PualOgilvie** pointed out, the compiler decide to let each row start on a word boundary, causing a disallignment) and you could scan them in loop with a pointer like this:

```
int i;
char *prt_1st = list_ch;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(list_ch); i++) {
    printf("Position: %d Element: %c\n", i, prt_1st[i]);
}
```

Or keeping the 2D nature:

```
char *prt_1st;
int dim = sizeof(list_ch) / sizeof(list_ch[0]);
for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
    prt_1st = list_ch[i];
    printf("The first char of row %d is %c\n", i, prt_1st[0]);
}
```

Comment: Why would the compiler lay them out contiguously in memory? Why shouldn't the compiler decide to let each row start on a word boundary (32/64 bit boundary) but a row is only 2 bytes?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie honestly, I thought it was stated in the standard, but I see your point

Comment: Your code works as well. Danke!